# How to continuously upload files with WinSCP

Tags: batch-file, ftp, winscp

I want my WinSCP script to loop.

Starting script (.bat file)

```
winscp.com /script=SyncToRemoteScript.txt
pause
```

My script (.txt file)

```
open ftp://usernam:password@myhost/ -hostkey="ssh-ed25XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX="
put D:\folder /home/myuser/public_html/wp-content/themes/newtheme
exit
```

I tried `GOTO` method like this – not working.

```
:start
open ftp://usernam:password@myhost/ -hostkey="ssh-ed25XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX="
put D:\folder /home/myuser/public_html/wp-content/themes/newtheme
goto start
```

Tried `while` also, but CMD tells me *"Unknown command 'While'"*. I googled that problem can solved by saving the file ASCII, but it's not working either.

Comment: Do you have ssh daemon enabled for your user on this machine? DO you have ssh daemon run?

Comment: I installed SSH Server and then went to host server and the files was there. I don't know which those files went to there after SSH Server installing, or is there some refreshing bug before. Now it is working great. 

```/log``` showing only path nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `goto` command in WinSCP.

But there's [`goto` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/goto) in Windows batch file, so you can do:

```
:start
winscp.com /script=SyncToRemoteScript.txt
goto start
```

---

For a bit more complex code, see WinSCP [Retrying Script example](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_retry).

---

Though as you seem to try to continuously update a remote directory, consider using:

- [`synchronize remote` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize) to update only modified files.
- [`keepuptodate` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_keepuptodate) to continuously update modified files (and you won't need any loop).

Comment: Lot of thanks, this keepuptodate command is what i have been looking for. Amazing, thanks!! :)

It scanning the chages alltime and update the remote directory when i edit something. Nice.